# Assigning properties on class dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, design-patterns, tdd

Lets say I have a class that takes a IFileLogger in as a constructor argument.

```
public MyClass : IClass
{
    private IFileLogger Logger;
    public MyClass(IFileLogger Logger)
    {
        this.Logger = Logger;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in that class it calls `Logger.Write("Data");`

IFileLogger has a property of DirectoryPath;

This needs to be set so that IFileLogger knows where to write the file to.

How does that get set?

My thoughts are to have a property on the class that gets set and then in the constructor have something like IFileLogger.DirectoryPath = this.DirectoryPath.

This seems wrong though as IClass would need to have the property in it and you end up creating a chain of properties that are only needed at the bottom level.

Can you help someone who can't see the wood for the trees?  Also would you write tests and how, to determine IFileLogger had its DirectoryPath populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I suggest that the design of your interface is the problem here and that your question is the indication of the smell?

The `IFileLogger` represents an interface your class depends on. As such, looking at the interface we see that there is a `Write` method. The thing is, `MyClass` doesn't really care how the logging happens, just that it conforms to the interface. With that being said, the thought that `MyClass` needs to know the directory location in order to tell the `IFileLogger` how to do it's job tells you that the responsibility is misplaced.

What does the code need the `IFileLogger`? Logging, right? Let's refactor the code a bit and implement the interface to the needs of the client, `MyClass`. He doesn't care *how* the logging happens, just that it *will* happen.

Rename the interface to `ILogger` instead.

```
public MyClass : IClass
{
    private ILogger Logger;
    public MyClass(ILogger Logger)
    {
        this.Logger = Logger;
    }
}
```

Now that there are no references to a "File" anywhere in this class makes it more obvious that the directory setting doesn't belong here. Where does it belong? Probably in the `FileLogger` itself.

Using Dependency Injection would leave you with something like:

```
main() {
  // Poor man's DI, no frameworks here
  var logger = new FileLogger("some/directory");
  var instance = new MyClass(logger);
  return instance.DoSomethingUsefulThatEventuallyGetsLogged();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Brandon

Answer (score 0):

How and where do you instantiate an IFileLogger, it sounds to be the place to set its property.

```
  builder.RegisterType<FileLogger>().WithParameter(new NamedParameter("directoryPath", @"c:\temp")).As<IFileLogger>();
```

With this configuration, any time you will use that builder to resolve IFileLogger, it will use "c:\Temp" as directoryPath.

Comment: In that case, The FileLogger constructor should take a RepositoryPath in parameter, (and set it to the RepositoryPath property of course), and you should inject the parameter while you are resolving  the IFileLogger.

Comment: Did you try to resolve the DirectoryoPath parameter with something like container.Resolve<FileLogger>(new NamedParameter("dirPath",@"c:\temp"));

Comment: No, I guess that could work but I'd need a static class that has the container in it

Comment: Does that mean when the IOC creates a instance of IFileLogger it will always use that parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would say that your object should be ready to use once constructed, and having to call other methods/properties to get it ready is just confusing. So the Logger should already have its DirectoryPath property set before passing it into MyClass. E.g:

```
SomeInitialisationMethod
    ()
{
    // or use IOC "factory" to create necessary concrete version.
    IFileLogger logger = new LoggerVariant("path");

    // MyClass can now use the ready to use logger. If we need to set the DirectoryPath, we can do it on this calling stack through the logger. 
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(logger);
```

Comment: What if MyClass ie IClass is a constructor argument on the class that has the InitlisationMethod? That's what my code looks like